# Scrolling UICollectionView in response to keyboard notification

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview, core-animation

I am building a messenger app.

My current keyboard notification function is as follows:

```
func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let keyboardFrame = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue()
            print(keyboardFrame)


            let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification


            bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame!.height : 0



            UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: { (completed) in

                    if isKeyboardShowing {
                        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: self.messages!.count - 1, inSection: 0)
                        self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
                    }

            })

    }
}
```

( *bottomConstraint.constant* is in reference to the message input text field that is either at the bottom of the screen or on top of the keyboard frame)

However, I want the actions in the completion parameters to occur simultaneously with the keyboard opening not AFTER the keyboard opens. Currently when I close the keyboard it seems to auto layout fine just not when I open it.

I've tried going about this many ways so far to no avail.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the block of code written in completion to happen simultaneously with the keyboard going down then you shouldn't write it in the completion block.
You can either use a dispatch_async before you call the animate with duration function so it might work concurrently as so:

```
   func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

            if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
                let keyboardFrame = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue()
                print(keyboardFrame)


                let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == UIKeyboardWillShowNotification


                bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame!.height : 0

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if isKeyboardShowing {
                    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: self.messages!.count - 1, inSection: 0)
                            self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
}


            UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {self.view.layoutIfNeeded()}, completion: nil})

    }
}
```

Comment: I needed the ScrollView to also move when my keyboard appeared, so I used a version of the above answer:  

       ** DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.scrollToBottomAnimated(animated: true)
        } **